# Duplicate row if a cell within a column contains text, then move values from one column to another?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a macro that goes through my data set and checks if there's any text in column W, if it does I would like the macro to duplicate the row beneath it, then move the values from Columns X and W to U and Q respectively.

My code at the moment is only trying to get the duplicate part down but its not working and I'm kind of stuck, could you have a look at it and help out?

```
Dim lastRow2 as Long
Dim cel as Range, srchRng as Range

lastRow2 = Worksheets("UPLOAD COPY").Cells(Rows.Count, 23).End(xlUp).Row
Set srchRng = Range("W2: W" & lastRow2)

For Each cel In srchRng
 If InStr(1, cel.Value, "*") > 0 Then
     cel.Offset(1).Insert
     cel.EntireRow.Copy cel.Offset(1)
     Set cel = cel.Offset(2)
 End If
Next cel
```

Comment: Wouldn't you rather like the duplicates in another worksheet? Does move mean copy from x and w to u and q and then delete from x and w? Do you want to do it to the old or the new row? Note that when inserting in column w, only the data in column w will be shifted down, and when later copying, data will be overwritten, and also the srchRng approach will not work if you correct the previous.

Comment: Hi VBasic, I need the data in the same sheet as its being uploaded to a client portal that requires a specific formatting.Yes, move means copy and delete - or you could use Cut and paste and I'd need the cell values moved in the newly duplicated row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Create Duplicate Rows

```
Option Explicit

Sub createDuplicateRows()
    
    Const wsName As String = "UPLOAD COPY"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const Col As Variant = "W" ' or 23
    Dim OldCols As Variant: OldCols = Array("W", "X") ' or 23, 24
    Dim NewCols As Variant: NewCols = Array("Q", "U") ' or 17, 21
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim CurrentRow As Long: CurrentRow = FirstRow
    Dim j As Long
    
    Do
        If ws.Cells(CurrentRow, Col).Value <> "" Then GoSub insertRow
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
    Loop Until CurrentRow > LastRow

    Exit Sub
   
insertRow:
    ws.Rows(CurrentRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ws.Rows(CurrentRow).EntireRow.Copy ws.Rows(CurrentRow + 1)
    CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
    GoSub changeValues
    LastRow = LastRow + 1
    Return

changeValues:
    For j = 0 To UBound(OldCols)
        ws.Cells(CurrentRow, NewCols(j)).Value _
          = ws.Cells(CurrentRow, OldCols(j)).Value
        ws.Cells(CurrentRow, OldCols(j)).ClearContents
    Next j
    Return

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

You can write the 'delete part' in a separate subroutine. Then you can do what I suggested in the comments. Sorry, I didn't realize that previously it would copy the already cleared (empty) values.

```
Option Explicit

Sub createDuplicateRows()
    
    Const wsName As String = "UPLOAD COPY"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    Const Col As Variant = "W" ' or 23
    Dim OldCols As Variant: OldCols = Array("W", "X", "X") ' or 23, 24, 24
    Dim NewCols As Variant: NewCols = Array("Q", "U", "Y") ' or 17, 21, 25
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim CurrentRow As Long: CurrentRow = FirstRow
    Dim j As Long
    
    Do
        If ws.Cells(CurrentRow, Col).Value <> "" Then GoSub insertRow
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
    Loop Until CurrentRow > LastRow

    Exit Sub
   
insertRow:
    ws.Rows(CurrentRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ws.Rows(CurrentRow).EntireRow.Copy ws.Rows(CurrentRow + 1)
    CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
    GoSub changeValues
    LastRow = LastRow + 1
    Return

changeValues:
    For j = 0 To UBound(OldCols)
        ws.Cells(CurrentRow, NewCols(j)).Value _
          = ws.Cells(CurrentRow, OldCols(j)).Value
    Next j
    GoSub deleteValues
    Return

deleteValues:
    For j = 0 To UBound(OldCols)
        ws.Cells(CurrentRow, OldCols(j)).ClearContents
    Next j
    Return

End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you very much. If I wanted to copy the value from column X to column Y also, would I just add "Y" to the NewCols array?

Comment: This array stuff works in pairs, so you have to add `X` again to `OldCols` and `Y` to `NewCols`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you again. I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Hi VBasic, sorry to bother you again but I'm wondering if you could help make it so the value from column X (or U after it is moved by the array) is copied to column Y before going to the next row? At the moment it moves the value between the columns and I need it to copy the value to column Y after it moves it originally.

Comment: @Treeko11: I've added another version.

Comment: Thank you so much, you've been an amazing help.